# If an event has a X% chance of happening this year, what are the odds of it happening on any given day

Tags: probability, statistics

background:  I am not great at statistics and probabilities.  I read something in the news (can't remember what right now, probably something Trump related) that said an event was X% chance of happening this year.  I was idly wondering how to figure out what the daily chance of that event happening would be.

I am thinking that it may be as simple as taking the odds and dividing it by the time period -- it makes sense in my head.  So if something had a 100% chance of happening in a year and all days are the same weight, then it would have a 50% chance to occur in the first 1/2 of the year and 50% chance to happen in the last 1/2 of the year.  Assuming that logic holds, then could I assume that each day would have a (1/365) = 0.274% chance of said event happening?

Comment: Yes, (a) if each day is equally likely and (b) it cannot happen on two or more different days

Comment: thank you -- like I said the thought just popped into my head and I wanted to confirm it was that simple.  All of the questions I looked up that were similar involved a lot more math =D

Comment: @Henry What would we do if it could happen on two or more different days?

Comment: Then perhaps it happens every day, which could push up the daily percentage probability to $100\%$.  Or perhaps something else might happen

Comment: I am unsure of what to do with the question at this point -- the direct answer was given here in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing old open questions -- the answer was given in the first comment to the question:

Yes, (a) if each day is equally likely and (b) it cannot happen on two or more different days.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know the subject we are dealing with.

It is written "So if something had a 100% chance of happening in a year AND all days are the same weight...".

But some situations are not so.

Let's talk about tornados, for example.

In southern states, peak tornado occurrence is March through May, while peak months in northern states are during the summer.

Reference http://www.virginiadot.org/travel/tornadoes.asp

If we consider the southern states, March, April and May will have more weight than the other months.

Comment: there was not a specific subject -- just a stray thought based on a throw-away comment.