# Given an actuarial life table, if rate of risk goes up at a steady rate throughout a year how could I determine specific odds on a day

Tags: probability, statistics

Based on a question  I asked on here earlier ([If an event has a X% chance of happening this year, what are the odds of it happening on any given day](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599813/if-an-event-has-a-x-chance-of-happening-this-year-what-are-the-odds-of-it-happ)) I was thinking about the odds different things -- and got on the thought of dying on any given day.  And yes I just turned 40.

-- looking up the latest numbers, I see that the probability of a 40 year old dying in a given year is 0.212%.  If all days are equal then the odds of dying in a given day would be (.00212/365)  .00058%. If I were to assume that the risk of dying went up linearly throughout the year -- how could I determine the odds of dying tomorrow?  (or any given day in the year?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just that one number we don't have enough information. How quickly (i.e., with what slope) is it going up linearly? It could be going up linearly very slightly, so it's close to .00058% every day (maybe .00057% on the first day of the year and .00059% on the last day of the year). It could be going up linearly more quickly, so it's close to .00001% on the first day of the year, and is all the way up to .00115% on the last day of the year. We'd probably need to compare with the numbers in the table for adjacent years -- or, better yet, find out what model the actuaries are using -- to get a more precise answer.

No matter what, though, those odds aren't terrible.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more -- If I knew the starting point -- say .000565 and the total odds of .212 could I determine the slope and then I would just add that to the starting point for each day of the year?

Comment: @StevenDeam Yes you could.